# How to set background image in CodeHS turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I need to set a custom image as my background. The problem is, CodeHS’s IDE or whatever is extremely limited and does not support the bgpic() function. Is there any workaround?

I tried importing tkinter, screen, and turtle, but none seem to support custom background images. I’m working straight from CodeHS’s Python Turtle application (not tkinter). It tells me that bgpic() is not defined or [module] has no attribute “bgpic()”. Is this just a result of CodeHS being really limited?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that CodeHS’s Python Turtle is a subset of the standard turtle library, suitable to run in a browser window.  You can access the screen object instance via `getscreen()` but it doesn't have a `bgpic` method:

> AttributeError: 'Screen' object has no attribute 'bgpic'

You have to work within the subset turtle API they provide.  (If it did work, how would you provide a file for `bgpic()` to use under this environment?)